# Pixabay API JSON parse with volley in android studio do not display in recyclerview item

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I'm facing a great problem, i am trying to build an app that fetch data from JSON file from a link the parse it with Volley. Now i want to display the data on a RecyclerView which doesn't seem to work, i'm pretty dure that my code is good but something doesn't seem to work and i can't find it. Please someone **HELP ME!**. This is my first time asking question on Stackoverflow. Guys Please **HELP ME!** going crazy Please!.

activity_home.xml

this seems to render as i tested with background color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/darker_grey"
            />
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the activity code

HomeActivity.java:

```
package com.example.pixabay;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ExampleAdapter mExampleAdapter;
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    parseJSON();
}

private void parseJSON(){
    String url = "https://pixabay.com/api/?key=28270765-21ee0e4f869cf621c16ee710e&q=kitten&image_type=photov";
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("hits");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject hit = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String creatorName = hit.getString("user");
                            String imageUrl = hit.getString("webformatURL");
                            int likeCount = hit.getInt("likes");

                            mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(imageUrl,creatorName,likeCount));
                        }

                        mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(MainActivity.this, mExampleList);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}
```

}

This is the layout i'm inflating from the adapter and set data from JSON file

Example_item.xml:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_creator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Creators Name"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_likes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Like: "/>

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

This is the Adapter class:

```
package com.example.pixabay;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder>{

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;

    public  ExampleAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList){
        mContext = context;
        mExampleList = exampleList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false);
        return new ExampleViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ExampleItem CurrentItem = mExampleList.get(position);

        String imageUrl = CurrentItem.getImageUrl();
        String creatorName = CurrentItem.getCreator();
        int likeCount = CurrentItem.getLikeCount();

        holder.mTextViewCreator.setText(creatorName);
        holder.mTextViewLikes.setText("Likes: " + likeCount);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(imageUrl).fit().centerInside().into(holder.mImageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExampleList.size();
    }

    public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public TextView mTextViewCreator;
        public TextView mTextViewLikes;

        public ExampleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            mTextViewCreator = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_creator);
            mTextViewLikes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_likes);
        }
    }
}
```

ViewHolder class:

```
package com.example.pixabay;

public class ExampleItem {

    private String mImageUrl;
    private String mCreator;
    private int mLikes;

    public ExampleItem(String imageUrl, String creator, int likes){
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;
        mCreator = creator;
        mLikes = likes;
    }

    public String getImageUrl(){
        return mImageUrl;
    }

    public String getCreator(){
        return mCreator;
    }

    public int getLikeCount(){
        return mLikes;
    }
}
```

Thanks You !

Comment: what response are you getting from api ? is the response code 200? did u check logcat, there might be some logs

Comment: i am getting image data, text and int data from the api,